# Button immediately be disabled when first time click itself

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I have my popup with Proceed button,what i need is,the button immediately be disabled when first time click itself and i have my code like,

```
 <button class="SmallBtn" type="button" onclick="ProceedImportData()" id="ProceedBtn">Proceed</button>
```

jquery like,

```
 function ProceedImportData() {
var hasClicked = false;
$('#ProceedBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    if (hasClicked === true) {
        $("#ProceedBtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
var PreUploadPreview =
    {
    };
$.ajax({
    url: '/Index/UploadedPreviewPage',
    data: JSON.stringify(PreUploadPreview),
    //        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            MTIErrorChw();
        }
    },
});
```

}

But code does not works. Kindly tell how to achieve this.

Comment: remove this condition if (hasClicked === true) {} use directly $("#ProceedBtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works good for me,

```
function ProceedImportData() {
$('#ProceedBtn').attr('disabled', true);
var PreUploadPreview ={};
$.ajax({
    url: '/Index/UploadedPreviewPage',
    data: JSON.stringify(PreUploadPreview),
    //        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {MTIErrorChw();}
    },
});}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the attribute disabled this way, and just after make the ajax call.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ProceedBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).attr('disabled',true);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Index/UploadedPreviewPage',
        data: JSON.stringify(PreUploadPreview),
        //        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                MTIErrorChw();
            }
        },
    });

    });

    }
    );
    </script>
     <button class="SmallBtn" type="button" id="ProceedBtn">Proceed</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't works. it showing MTIErrorChw page before the button get clicks.

Comment: Can you post your code? Above should be executed as following, click then button disabled, then the ajax call.

Comment: Provided answer for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need call the function on document ready:

```
$(function(){
     ProceedImportData();
      ...
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try in this way...
[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bharathi038/eps5Lbt3/2/)

```
onclick="ProceedImportData(this)"
```

in your button tags

```
function ProceedImportData(ele) {
var hasClicked = false;
$(ele).prop('disabled', true);
var PreUploadPreview =
    {
    };
$.ajax({
    url: '/Index/UploadedPreviewPage',
    data: JSON.stringify(PreUploadPreview),
    //        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            MTIErrorChw();
        }
    },
});

}
```